# can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template' angular 5

Tags: angular5

I've been told to switch from ngOutletContext to ngTemplateOutletContext for my upgrade from angular 4.4 to 5.2.

What is bugging me is that I do not have a single directive ngOutletContext in any of my  tags.

For example, all of my ng-template tags look like this:

```html
<ng-template tabHeading>

or

<ng-template ngFor let-breadcrumb [ngForOf]="breadcrumbs" let-last = last>

or

<ng-template ngbTabContent>
```

I'm guessing it is a problem with some of the dependencies that I have installed?

Here is the list, would appreciate a second pair of eyes on this:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.1.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "d3": "^4.11.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "ng-bootstrap": "1.6.3",
    "ng-select": "1.0.0-beta.6",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-progressbar": "~2.0.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.3.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.395",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.8",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.4.1",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.43",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/mongodb": "^2.2.11",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.23",
    "@types/node": "7.0.5",
    "@types/rx": "^4.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "snyk": "^1.70.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching on your node_module folder